# AWS SAM script conversion to Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have converted AWS Lambda funtions which were in AWS Cloudformation into Terraform.

Is there a way to convert AWS SAM functions from cloudformation meaning in the Cloudformation the resource is AWS::Serverless::Function . can this be converted into terraform

For example in Cloudformation the syntax for Lambda is

```
     "Type": "AWS::LAMBDA::FUNCTION".
```

Its equivalent in Terraform is

```
     resource "aws_lambda_function"
```

What is the equivalent in Terraform for

```
    "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function"
```

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, there is no such equivalent in TF itself. RF maps to [AWS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-apis.html), and `AWS::Serverless::Function` is higher level, convenience construct not covered by the API. Thus, there is no single resource in TF that would match `AWS::Serverless::Function`.

However, there is [terraform-aws-modules /
terraform-aws-lambda](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda) module which should make it easier to implement the functionality of `AWS::Serverless::Function` .

Comment: greatly appreicate for the reply. thank you